# c++ reading previous function stack frame

Tags: c++, arrays, stack

I have an array created by a function(named write). After that function returns, I call another function(named read) that read an array of the same size from the stack directly.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void write();
void read();

int main(void)
{
    write();
    read();

    return 0;
}

// Write an array of 10 ints to the stack
void write() {
    int array[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        array[i] = i;
}

// Read an array of 10 from stack
void read() {
    int array[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cout << array[i] << endl;
}
```

Shouldn't the read function read the same array content from the stack?

What I find interesting is that the first and second array values are always the same. The first(at index 0) is a negative garbage value. The second(at index 1) is 0.

As far I understand, when a function returns, it doesn't clean up it's stack frame. So when read reads the stack, it read the same values written by write.
But Why is the first and second values always like this?

Comment: Because something else used that space in between. If you're using MSVC, then possibly one of the runtime check functions.

Comment: Yes.. But what peaked my interest is why always the first and second values only? why is the first always a garbage value and the second always a 0?

Comment: And, please, define what do you mean by "clean up it's stack frame". Do you think it should set every value, not used anymore, to 0? To any random value? Why should it do it?

Comment: @MAA, undefined behavior means exactly that, if the same behavior happened 5 times in a row, there is no guarantee that the same will happen 6th time.

Comment: 'clean up' isn't the correct word. According to my understanding, it simply doesn't do anything to its stack frame upon returning. It just lets go of it.  I hope you did not read it like I was expecting it to 'clean up' the stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, this behavior is completely undefined, so even though you run this code 1000 times and see this behavior you might see something different the 1001th time. Further, what you are seeing and why is going to be very implementation dependent. If you're really curious about understanding this better, I recommend you look at the assembly code being generated by your compiler and you'll get a better sense of what's going on with the stack. How you'd do this is, again, implementation dependent, but with gcc you can pass the `--save-temps` option to the compiler and it will spit out it's intermediate files for you to peruse. This can be very educational!

Comment: One of these days, I will learn how that mumbo jumbo called assembly works :). Thanks Turn

Answer (score 1):

The arrays occupy the same general vicinity in the stack space, but it's just a coincidence. If there were more variables in either read() or write(), that won't be the case anymore. The structure of the stack frame is an implementation detail in the compiler - it depends on many things, like the variables in the function, the level of optimization, temporary storage space that compiler might allocate on the stack, unwind data for exceptions the function or its callees might throw... In short, don't ever rely on it.

From the standpoint of the C++ standard, reading from an uninitialized variable (like `array` within `read`) is an Undefined Behavior - anything could happen, from getting bogus values up to a program crash.